# How to include a mix of NSString and direct text input when setting an NSUserDefault?

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have a simple bit of code for which I can't seem to find the correct syntax:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *savedPrefix = [defaults stringForKey:@"stringPrefix"];
[defaults setObject:@"%@red_2-3.aiff" savedPrefix, forKey:@"myDefault"];
```

...So all I am trying to do is set 'myDefault' to (my NSString savedPrefix)+"red_2-3.aiff"

Can someone please help me adjust my syntax/method to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate a `NSString` with `stringWithFormat`. Something like this will work:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *savedPrefix = [defaults stringForKey:@"stringPrefix"];
[defaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@red_2-3.aiff", savedPrefix] forKey:@"myDefault"];
```

I prefer to break this a little more, like this: (it's the same thing, more granulated)

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *savedPrefix = [defaults stringForKey:@"stringPrefix"];
NSString *stringToBeSaved = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@red_2-3.aiff", savedPrefix]
[defaults setObject:stringToBeSaved forKey:@"myDefault"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response and nice explanation! Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
[defaults setObject:[savedPrefix stringByAppendingString:@"red_2-3.aiff"] forKey:@"myDefault"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[defaults setObject: [savedPrefix stringByAppendingString: @"red_2-3.aiff"]
             forKey: @"myDefault"]
```